# How to predict a portfolio's reversion?

Tags: portfolio, prediction, mean-reversion

Sorry if this has been asked before. I've been baffled by a question I'm facing.

Assuming I know there are some certain demands for some stocks in near future, and I put them in a basket as a portfolio. What I found is in short period, prices of some of them keep increasing and then at certain point revert. This reversion behavior is very clear for some symbols but less clear for others. General feeling is it has something to do with the saturation of the supplies to the demands. It's also coupled with the fluctuation of the overall market.

My perplexities are:

1. How to predict the reversion of single stocks with some confidence probability/internal, with overall market condition excluded?
2. How to do the same for the portfolio? After all, returns are measured by the aggregation of the portfolio.
3. If it makes it easier to remove the assumption of known demands, then in general, how to predict a single name and a basket's reversion with confidence probability/interval?

Kind of lost where to start. Some leads or links of papers will be enough to point to some directions.

Thanks!